# What does JTable's bind function do and why it is useful?

Tags: joomla-3.x, model, jtable

When writing a view which either edits creates a record, the model extends admin model which requires `getTable()` and `getForm()`.

Now the confusion is how the `loadForm()` function knows the number of fields in the table associated with the model and what the role of the `bind()` function is.

**It's not clear to me how the table class and form talk to each other and where**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your form is defined by your XML form (typically located in models/forms). You choose to have the same names as those in your database as those field names but actually it isn't compulsory.

You can think of the table as being like a wrapper around a row to insert. You go through a 3 stage process.

`bind` takes the array of data that comes from your form and then stores any data from it into the table class.

`check` then runs sanity checks on the data that you have binded into the table class

`store` then stores the binded data into the database table.

However what's important is the data that is stored in the class. This means that the names of the fields in your form are to an extent irrelevent. For example. You could have a field in your form called `foobar` and then in your bind method do:

```
public function bind($src, $ignore = array())
{
    $this->tableVar = $src['foobar'];
    parent::bind($src, $ignore);
}
```

And this will try and store the `foobar` variable from your form as a column called `tableVar` in your database

EDIT:

This is because the parent bind method will bind data to the class as a class var

```
public function bind($src, $ignore = array())
{
    foreach ($src as $field => $value)
    {
        $this->$field = $value;
    }
}
```

and then will attempt to match `$field` to a database column storing the value if it exists. So the importance of setting `$this->tablevar` above is that is the column in your database was `tablevar` and you didn't have a column called foobar then now it gets stored into the database.

Comment: how this ($this->tableVar = $src['foobar'];) will affect the bind function as we are passing $src without changing the name of 'foobar' instead we are passing foobar value to tableVar.? and yes thanks also

Comment: added an edit to try and help you understand :)

Answer (score 3):

The Form does not know anything about the fields in your database. It's getting its fields by your XML definition. The `bind()` function just adds the data to the object, while `store()` will post the binded data to your database.

In other words: You are responsible for correlating fields/properties.